# How to uninstall a plugin in Vim 8?

Tags: vimrc

On Linux, how to uninstall a plugin in Vim 8 other than removing the plugin code using a Linux command line `rm` command?
That is to say, is there a way to remove a plugin while in a Vim 8 session and (therefore) does not require a user to go to the Linux command line?  Like `:PlugClean <plugin name>`?
Or perhaps something in the `.vimrc` file that can be added?
Is there a `packdelete plugin` which does the opposite of `packadd plugin`.

I am using the Vim 8 native plugin manager and I want to stick with that plugin manager.

Comment: FWIW vim8 doesn't have "native plugin manager", so it is up to you or real plugin manager (like `minpac`) to take care of "managing" plugin un/installation.

Comment: @MaximKim https://shapeshed.com/vim-packages/

Comment: Packages support is a super nice feature... but it is not plugin manager at all. Have a look at minpac that uses packages feature of vim and can install/update/remove packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a conceptual misunderstanding here. What Vim routinely calls "a plugin" is rather "a configuration extension". Once a script file was loaded, it is cached into RAM and never forgotten until application ends. (It still could be overwritten but it's not the same thing as "removing").

Some "plugin managers" may have implemented `:PlugClean` or similar command. However, in practice it's just a wrapper over `rm` tool. (Something you can easily do yourself if you really wish).

Concerning `:packadd`, it scans `opt` sub-tree and adds an ("optional") plugin into `&runtimepath`. However, as I already said, once a plugin was added, the user is not able "to undo" this, and hence "the opposite to packadd" cannot be implemented.

Comment: Excellent answer.  But is there an equivalent”:PlugClean” for the Vim 8.x native plug-in manager?  Or are we left with just doing an “rm” from the command line?

Comment: Also, if one cannot uninstall a plug-in other than removing or renaming the plug-in code, can a plug-in be temporarily “disabled” using the Vim 8.x native plug-in manager?  I noticed that on Vim 8.c startup you can ignore all plug-ins but I’m interested on how to disable only one.

Comment: @tale852150 1. No builtin command exists; user has to do `:!rm -rf  dirname` or `:call delete("dirname", "rf")` himself. 2. To skip loading a plugin there are two options: a) put it under `opt` and load it with `:packadd` only if really needed, or b) define a "guard variable", like `let g:loaded_pluginname = 0` in your vimrc. This is not a language feature but rather a common convention that mostly used to bypass standard plugins shipped with Vim.

Comment: Thank you again for your input.  It has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the plugin line for the specific plugin in your .vimrc.
   -Ex. Plug 'myplugin/myplug'
2. Save file.
3. Source your .vimrc file. Execute `source` from command mode.
4. Execute `PlugClean`

The above steps works for vim-plug. Replace PlugClean with PluginClean for vundle.

Comment: Does it matter if the plug-in is a filetype or global plug-in?

Comment: Also, I’m looking on how can this be done with the Vim 8 native plug-in not the vim-plug plug-in manager.

Comment: As Matt said above, native package manager requires a little intervention. My apologies for missing that portion of the question.

Comment: not a problem- no need to apologize.  But with vim-plug, does PlugClean work differently between filetype vs global plug-ins? Thx.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: It is based on the path configured on the sourced .vimrc file. For instance the docs show this for the path for vim plug to look.
plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
So PlugClean would operate within the folder ~/.vim/plugged